# How do I select specific li based on id attribute

Tags: css

I have this ul

```
 <ul class="mobile-demo">
    <li>
        <img alt="" class="-logo" src="../assets/images/Logo@2x.png" />
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item " id="mainPgae" style="margin-right: 90px !important;">
        <a class="btn nav-link active" href="../FrontEnd/home.aspx">
    
        
        الرئيسية
        
        
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item history" id="history">
        <a href="../FrontEnd/History.aspx">تاريخ التأسيس</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item mission" id="mission">
        <a href="../FrontEnd/Mission.aspx">الهدف والرؤية</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item " id="news">
        <a href="../FrontEnd/news.aspx">الأخبار</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item gallery" id="album">
        <a href="../FrontEnd/gallery.aspx">الصور</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item videos" id="video">
        <a href="../FrontEnd/videos">الفيديو</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What is the css selector that will get me news one.

I tired

#mobile-demo ul li  #news {
margin-bottom: 0rem !important;
}

also

I tired

#mobile-demo ul li[id="news "]{
margin-bottom: 0rem !important;
}

also I added news class

#mobile-demo ul li[class="news "]{
margin-bottom: 0rem !important;
}

nothing worked

Any luck ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use like below. Do not use `space` between `ul` & `#mobile-demo` because `#mobile-demo ul` means it will find every `ul` inside element with id `#mobile-demo`. You need `ul` which has id as `#mobile-demo` so use `ul#mobile-demo`. Similarly for `li` also.

Moreover the code you have posted is having `ul` with class `mobile-demo` not `id` so use class selector `(.)` instead of id selector `(#)`. Or add  `id="mobile-demo"` in your `ul` element.

```
ul.mobile-demo li#news { margin-bottom: 0rem !important; }
```

Refer [CSS Selectors W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more details.

Try it below.

```css
ul#mobile-demo li#news {
  margin-bottom: 0rem !important;
}

ul#mobile-demo li#mainPage {
  margin-right: right:inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mobile-demo" id="mobile-demo">
  <li>
    <img alt="" class="s-logo" src="" />
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item " id="mainPage" style="margin-right: 90px !important;">
    <a class="btn nav-link active" href="../FrontEnd/home.aspx">
        الرئيسية
     </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item history" id="history">
    <a href="../FrontEnd/History.aspx">تاريخ التأسيس</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item mission" id="mission">
    <a href="../FrontEnd/Mission.aspx">الهدف والرؤية</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item " id="news">
    <a href="../FrontEnd/news.aspx">الأخبار</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item gallery" id="album">
    <a href="../FrontEnd/gallery.aspx">الصور</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item videos" id="video">
    <a href="../FrontEnd/videos">الفيديو</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it worked for news one but not main one.    ul#mobile-demo li#mainPage 
         { 
             margin-right:inherit !important; 
         }

Comment: You have typo out there. In html you have `mainPgae` instead of `mainPage`. `a` & `g` are misplaced.

Comment: how can I create a sub nav under <a href="../FrontEnd/History.aspx">تاريخ التأسيس</a>

Comment: Hope this links will help https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/, https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp

Comment: I need it for the samle structure the submenuew

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector:

```
li#history
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405338/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-telerikgridhtmleditorcolumn